Voltage over capacitor in parallel RC network with current limited DC voltage source
Consider the following RC network:
DC voltage source \$V_{s}\$, in series with resistor \$R_1\$, in series with capacitor \$C\$, which has parallel to it another resitor \$R_2\$.

For this network:
\$V_C = \frac{V_0}{\alpha}(1-exp(\frac{-\alpha t}{R_1C}))\$
Where: \$\alpha=\frac{R_1}{R_2}+1\$
How does this equation change when the maximum current of the voltage source is limited?
If the following values are assumed: \$C_1 = 210\mu F, R_1=50\Omega, R_2=3000\Omega, V_s= 300V, V_0=0V, i_{max}=100mA \$

LTSpice shows that \$5\tau\$ is reached after approximately 2.375 seconds for the case where the voltage source is limited at \$100mA\$, while in the unlimited case it is reached after 50 milliseconds, which differs by a factor of approximately 46, which seems really random to me. Additionally, the addition of the parallel resistor \$R_2\$ makes it such that the current through the capacitor is not a piecewise function consisting of a linear and an inversely exponential part. Anyone who knows how this circuit should be analysed when the voltage source is current limited?


For the case where the parallel capacitor, the voltage would just linearly increase until \$t = \frac{CV}{I_{max}}=0.63s\$, as can be seen in the image below:

Please rotate R1 so that when you plot current it's in the right direction/polarity. Next, separate the voltage plot from the current plot i.e. stack them vertically using the same time frame. Next, you should properly explain in your words that you are using a constant current diode to achieve current limiting. Next, you should add a reference plot for when the diode isn't present. And finally, if you experimented with much higher current limits (like starting at 10 amps and reducing to 100 mA) you would see that if there is still a question, it will be different to the one you asked above.

My apologies for the lack of proper conventions, the schematic was put together quite hastily. I have indeed experimented with higher current limits, and for a current limit that is higher than the current that would initially flow through the capacitor in an unlimited case, which would be 6A here, no changes will be present. For current limits lower than that 6A limit, the function can be approximated with a piecewise function, of which the first part is linear, but much lower than that limit, you'll end up with the same situation that is mentioned above, so I still have the same question.

Consider the equivalent circuit while the diode is limiting current:
We have a current source in series with a resistor and voltage source.  The voltage source and resistor are irrelevant -- the current is constant regardless of their presence -- so they can be removed without change:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
(C is just a default value for illustration)
Finally, we can transform the Norton equivalent current source into a Thevenin equivalent voltage source, of equal resistance and V = IR voltage.
Whereas the unlimited circuit has the resistors acting in parallel, hence the approx. 3000/50 ratio in charge speed.
You may find it intuitive to check the current flow through the voltage source or resistor, when unlimited: obviously, the peak current flow is much greater, hence the charging much faster as well.
In the case where I1 > V1 / R2, a piecewise solution will occur (as you note in comments), and we take the exponential with the longer time constant from zero until current limits ceases, and then set up the exponential with the shorter time constant having an initial condition of the first exponential's break point.  (These formulas are left as an exercise for the reader.)
The overall time constant (from zero to some RC multiple -- for whichever value of "R" we wish to choose..!) will of course depend critically on where that breakpoint occurs; note that we must express such an overall property as an effective time constant, because it's not, err, constant at all, it depends critically on all these parameters.
